Concrete example on the commutative diagram of comparison functor
I am trying to familiarize myself with the properties of monad. I discovered in nlab the following convoluted picture about the whole story.
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comparison+functor
It is quite a big picture. I am aware that everything has been unfolded in CWM already, and I believe that I can do the diagram chase. It seems to me, however, that is rather hard to remember this picture with concrete examples. May I please ask if there are any very typical examples that can help me remember what the picture is telling?
More precisely, I would like a pair of an adjunction, together with the associate monad, unit, count, and the associated Kleisli category and Elienberg-Moore category that fits in the picture, so the arrows in the picture say something useful about this monad.

In practice, the Eilenberg-Moore category is more important due to the utility of Barr-Beck. Check Riehl's "category theory in context" for a good source on this stuff, chapter 5 (iirc) covers monads. It's available online

@FShrike Thanks a lot for the comment! If possible, I would appreciate if you may expand the Barr-Beck reference in more details or give a concrete reference on it.

Well, firstly the Barr-Beck theorem is discussed in Riehl’s book. I have it on good word that this theorem is of great practical use in advanced algebraic geometry and the infinity-categorical version is also, allegedly, very useful; so from that perspective, the picture is just: any right adjoint $U:A\to B$ factors through a map from $A$ to $T$-algebras on $B$ and sometimes (usefully) this map is an equivalence. The picture that any adjunction creates a monad and comonad is easier to understand. And somehow all monads arise from adjunctions.

I’ve never seen this big nLab diagram before, don’t worry. All monads arise from adjunctions and the Kleisli, EM categories are just offering universal choices of such adjunction.
